# select the result of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, rdlc, dynamic-pivot

I have result of stored procedure which is using dynamic pivot.
I need to select the result, because I want to create rdlc report.
In RDLC, it's using select at dataadapter, but I have a problem with that because I used pivot stored procedure.
Can you help me with this issue, how to select the result of stored procedure, which the fields are dynamic.
Thank you..

Comment: Have you considered using a Matrix in the RDLC? That way you can do the pivoting in the report, rather than in the stored procedure...

Comment: I don't think that's even possible because the RDLC dataset has to know the fields before you can use them in expressions; that's why there is a "Refresh Fields" button in the properties windows of the dataset. You should consider applying what @MattGibson said above.

Comment: @MattGibson Well, i never heard that before. What's that anyway?